# Check if variable has value the opposite way?

Tags: php, variables, if-statement, conditional-statements

I have this PHP if statement that I am trying to firgure out. 
I know what the result is, but I have not seen this before (probably my bad).
Who can help me understand the code below? Why is `$a` showing and not `$b`? Because `$a` is first in line?

```
<?php
$a = 'has a value';
$b = 'this one too!';
if (($href = $a) || ($href = $b)) { 
    echo $href;
    //Result is 'has a value'.  
}
?>
```

Comment: Because `=` is assignment, and $a is true-y, so `($href = $a)` evaluates to `true`. Since the first expression is true, and the condition is an `OR`, the second expression doesn't need to evaluate for the `if` to pass, so doesn't run. Therefore, $href is $a.

Comment: It's because $a comes first in the conditional, because of `||` - it doesn't need to check the rest of the statement, it will execute the code (so $href will always = $a in this case)

Comment: Thanks, at first I did'nt undestand what the logic was to put a assignment (=) within an IF statement, but I see how this could be useful now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`||` uses "short-circuit" evaluation. If the first part of the expression is true, then the second part will not be evaluated. In PHP,

> The value of an assignment expression is the value assigned.

<sub>([quoted from the `=` documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.assignment.php))</sub>

so in this case the expression `($href = $a)` has a value of the assigned value, `'has a value'`. That string evaluates to true (see "[converting to boolean](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php#language.types.boolean.casting)"), so the second assignment will not be executed.

---

FYI, for another way to write this that's a little less repetitive, you can do this:

```
if ($href = $a ?: $b) { 
    echo $href;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this extensive answer(Y) At first I did'nt undestand what the logic was to put a assignment (=) within an IF statement, but I see how this could be useful now.